# Cosa significa la frase: le parole che ci stanno dentro?

Tags: word-usage, particles

L'ho sentito in una conversazione, ma non il resto,  volevo sapere perché si è usato "ci stanno".

Comment: Temo che senza il contesto del discorso sia impossibile rispondere a questa domanda.

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE! Sono d'accordo con @DenisNardin: sai qualcosa di più sull'argomento della conversazione?

Comment: No perché l'ho sentito per strada da due passeggeri, quindi nessun modo di trovare il resto, mi sembrava nuovo il modo di questa frase.

Answer (score 3):

Premesso che una risposta completa ce la potrebbero dare solo i due sconosciuti che conversavano, in una frase di questo tipo “ci” è un avverbio di luogo (come in “Conosci Firenze?” “Sì, *ci* vado spesso”). Perciò, “che ci stanno dentro” è equivalente al più goffo “che stanno dentro a ciò”.

Evidentemente si stava parlando di qualcosa che contiene delle parole (un libro, un discorso) e, appunto, delle parole che esso conteneva.

(Un'altra cosa che in certe parti d'Italia può forse suonare poco abituale, ma non so se è a questo che si riferisce l'OP, è l'uso del verbo “stare” dove altri userebbero “essere”: “le parole che ci sono dentro”.)

Comment: Ti ringrazio tanto per la risposta,  io vivo a Lecco, secondo te qui si usa come che hai indicato tu?

Comment: “Ci” è usato in tutta Italia; “[stare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/stare/)” è un normale verbo italiano, ma forse usato così suona un po' meno abituale al Nord.

Answer (score 2):

"Starci dentro" nel gergo giovanile può anche essere usato in riferimento a qualcosa di bello e/o divertente e/o *cool*. 
Vedi questo link per un esempio http://temi.repubblica.it/espresso-slangopedia/2008/11/19/starci-dentro/. È quindi possibile che con l'espressione che hai sentito i due passeggeri (o forse intendevi *passanti*, a meno che non ti trovassi in un aeroporto o luogo simile) volessero dire "le parole *cool*" o "le parole del momento".

Comment: Corretto, anche se, dovendo tirare ad indovinare, credo che l'interpretazione di DaG sia piu' probabile nel contesto di due passanti che chiaccherano.